# A strange message full of dice came in my mail

Tags: cipher, story, dice

So I got a package today that contained the strangest contents. It was a set of dice, each of them numbered in one of the corners. Arranged, this is what numbers  or characters displayed on each dice,

> 111122 011111 222222 223333 ------ 111222 000001 222223 333334 333344 333444 000111 222221 222111 222233 333344 111122 011111 333334 011111 000111 222333 222233 001111 001111 111222 222223 011111 222233 333334 111222 222333 222233 000000

None of the dice indicate what is front, back, top, or bottom, so I don't think it matters what order the numbers are in on the dice. I can't make sense of it, can you help me decipher what these dice are trying to tell me?

Comment: What's the point of a die with only one number on  it?

Comment: @JonMarkPerry, I don't know, this is just what I received? Maybe they're really just cubes with numbers? hmm...

Comment: Does the "------" part means that there's no number on these dice ?

Comment: @RémiHenry, no that's the character that was on them. I think it's either a hyphen or a minus sign?

Comment: Can't dice be numbered differently even without regard to orientation? For instance, the first die could have the 2s adjacent or opposing.

Comment: @noedne, the way I put them in there is top, left, front, right, back, bottom, if that makes any difference, but I don't think it does.

Comment: @Joe-You-Know you're back! Welcome back sir!

Comment: @El-Guest, not quite back yet, I've been preparing for my 100th riddle and I wanted to pass this by first. My riddles 86 - 100 are all connected, and I wanted to post something real quick before I come back in full force. It'll probably be mid April before those are ready.

Comment: @Joe-You-Know well I’m anticipating your return! Love those riddles!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems to translate to:

> Help - I am stuck in the second dimension.

Found by

> Taking the sum of each dice, and decoding it as A1Z26, giving:
> help ------ iamstuckintheseconddimension 0 
>  (Taking 0 as a period per Joe-You-Know's comment)

Comment: Nice job, I didn't think it would be decoded that quickly. Just fyi rot13(Gur mrebrf pna or vagrecergrq nf n crevbq.)